# how to export datagrid to .xls AND/OR .pdf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, pdf, datagridview

i need to export a datagrid to excel and pdf however i can't do that through a reportviewer because i don't have a database, i set manually the values of my datagrid. Is there a way to do that, preferably without a third party library.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

if you can't use reportviewer, maybe you can try for:

1. XLS: NPOI http://code.google.com/p/npoi/
2. PDF: PDFSharp or MigraDoc http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Answer (score 1):

ReportViewer doesn't need a database. It can be run in [Local Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) mode. If you care about formatting, this is absolutely the best way. For excel with no formatting you could output a CSV file, but writing a PDF without a third party library is going to be a challenge.

Comment: Hope it goes well. I use this option extensively in a tool at my work. The only thing I had trouble with initially was setting up the data sources. This link might help with that: [Data Sources and Local Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724(v=vs.80).aspx)